# Angular verify conditions one after another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an use case in which I need to verify a few conditions. If the previous one fails I should not verify next one but based on the previous one I should display dialog with title and description indicates what went wrong.
Assuming I have an service (pseudo code)
// verify-condition.service.ts

```
public validateConditions():Observable<ValidationData> {
  public validateConditions(): Observable<ValidationModal> {
    const hasContract$: Observable<ContractStatus> = this.getContractSignStatus();
    const hasTUTSigned$: Observable<boolean> = this.hasTUTSigned();
    const doData$: Observable<DoModel> = this.getDoData();
    return combineLatest([hasContract$, hasTUTSigned$, doData$]).pipe(
      map(([hasContract, hasTUTSigned, doData,]) => {
        const validationConditions: ValidationModal = {
          conditions: {
            hasContract: hasContract === ContractStatus.SIGNED,
            hasTUTSigned,
            wasSigned: doData.wasSigned,
            valid: doData.valid,
            signDate: doData.signDate,
          }
        };
        return validationConditions;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and then in the component I'm using it

```
 public verifyProcess(): void {
  verifyConditionService.validateConditions().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((validationData:ValidationData=> {
      if (validationData) {
        this.modalValidationService.openModal(validationData);
      } else {
        this.beginProcess();
      }
    })
  }
```

Thing is that in the service I run all the conditions at once using combineLatest but I would like to run them one by one and if the first fails I should not run the next one but instead throw an error or in some other way indicate that it fails and return data needed to display dialog.

```
  public validateConditionsInOrder():Observable<ValidationData|boolean> {
    return this.getContractSignStatus().pipe(
        map((signStatus:ContractStatus)=>{
            if(signStatus !== ContractStatus.SIGNED){
                return {
                    hasContract:signStatus
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }),
        switchMap((previousCondition)=>{ 
            if(!previousCondition){ // so if previous condition failed I DO NOT want to check the next conditions but instead stop verification and return the data from the previous condition

            } else {
                this.hasTUTSigned(); // if the previous condition is OK, I move on to the next one and so on. and if here or the next condition fails I always need to know what went wrong in orther to display dialog based on the info
            }
        })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Would it be a problem if you just put all validation request in an array and fokJoin them, and then just loop through the response and pick the first error?

Comment: I don't think so, all the API calls returns some responses and they are not an errors. eg. this.getContractSignStatus(); can return different statuses but in my case I need to verify if its is SIGNED. If yes move to the next condition if not return an appropriate object based on which dialog is displayed

Comment: You can build a pipe which chains switchMaps to subscribe to the following Observable depending on the condition from the previous one. That way you avoid making unnecessary server requests.

Comment: @WillAlexander could you please show some pseudo code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably create a chain of observables/calls using `iif` operator. Not the nicest solution, but you can use it as an inspiration and implement a custom pipe, as **@Will Alexander** has mentioned.

```typescript
public validateConditions(): Observable<ValidationModal> {
  // Prepared validateConditions object, so that you partial Observables 
  // have something to work with. Adjust accordingly
  const result = {
    hasContract: false,
    hasTUTSigned: false,
    wasSigned: false,
    valid: null,
    signDate: null,
  };

  // Map hasContract state directly and use it later
  const hasContract$: Observable<ContractStatus> =
    this.getContractSignStatus().pipe(
      map((hasContract) => ({
        ...result,
        hasContract: hasContract === ContractStatus.SIGNED,
      }))
    );

  const hasTUTSigned$: Observable<boolean> = this.hasTUTSigned();
  const doData$: Observable<DoModel> = this.getDoData();

  // Instead of combineLatest, start with piping hasContract$
  return hasContract$.pipe(
    switchMap((validateConditions) =>
      iif(
        //If hasContract is true, chain hasTUTSigned$ and map result
        //Otherwise return previous state of validateConditions
        () => validateConditions.hasContract,
        hasTUTSigned$.pipe(
          map((hasTUTSigned) => ({ ...validateConditions, hasTUTSigned }))
        ),
        of(validateConditions) // Return unchanged data
      )
    ),
    switchMap((validateConditions) =>
      iif(
        // Same as before, but check different condition, map different data
        () => validateConditions.hasTUTSigned,
        doData$.pipe(map((data) => ({ ...validateConditions, ...data }))),
        of(validateConditions) // Return unchanged data
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Using `iif` and `of` you can either chain real observables or pass unmodified validateConditions object if condition weren't met.

Comment: thx, but how to stop executing the next switchMap if the previous condition fails? so I like to run hasContract$ but not to trigger the next switchMap if hasContract is false?

Comment: just add `filter` operator before a `switchMap` you want to exclude. But this will stop the execution completely. In the code above, if the condition is not met, you just return what was in the stream previously

Comment: I figured it out this. I just moved switchMaps to the conditions instead of the main stream, so that I can check conditions one by another and if it fails I return the previous validation and stops executing

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```js
const getCondition = (validity: boolean) => of(validity).pipe(delay(1000));

const condition1$ = getCondition(true);
const condition2$ = getCondition(true);
const condition3$ = getCondition(true);

const errorIfFalseCondition =
  (error: string) =>
  <T>(obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
    obs$.pipe(
      tap((x) => {
        if (!x) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      })
    );

concat(
  condition1$.pipe(errorIfFalseCondition(`Condition 1 was not respected`)),
  condition2$.pipe(errorIfFalseCondition(`Condition 2 was not respected`)),
  condition3$.pipe(errorIfFalseCondition(`Condition 3 was not respected`))
)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log(`[DEBUG] A condition has passed`)),
    ignoreElements(),
    tap({ complete: () => console.log(`All conditions passed`) })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

And a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gqvhpx?file=index.ts) where you can toggle the conditions to return false when you want to see the different outputs.

The conditions are ran one after another, sequentially. If one fails (throws), it'll kill the queue and you'll get the error that you defined. So you could downstream easily rely on the error message to display something in your modal.

Have a play and see that at the moment with all conditions set to true, after 3s, you get the message "All conditions passed" but if you set one to `false` you'll get an error and it'll stop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
public validateConditions () {
    const hasContract$: Observable<ContractStatus> = this.getContractSignStatus();
    const hasTUTSigned$: Observable<boolean> = this.hasTUTSigned();
    const doData$: Observable<DoModel> = this.getDoData();
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
        const condi = {
            hasContract : null,
            hasTUTSigned: null,
            wasSigned   : null,
            valid       : null,
            signDate    : null,
        }
        
        concat(
            hasContract$.pipe(tap(hasContract => condi.hasContract = hasContract === ContractStatus.SIGNED)), 
            hasTUTSigned$.pipe(tap(hasTUTSigned => condi.hasTUTSigned = hasTUTSigned)),
            doData$.pipe(tap(doData => Object.assign(condi, {
                wasSigned : doData.wasSigned,
                valid     : doData.valid,
                signDate  : doData.signDate,
            }))), 
        ).subscribe({
            complete    : ()    => subscriber.next(condi),
            error       : error => {
                console.error(error);       // handle error
                subscriber.next(condi);     
            }
        })
    }).pipe(take(1), map(condi => ({conditions  : condi,}) as ValidationModal))
}
```

the base of my method relies on rxjs.concat to chain and control sequence of each observable, then translate the data by creating a new Observable Class

**behaviour:**

- the later observable will wait until the previous observable is completed
- when an observable receive reply, update its respective validation property using tap operator
- when all 3 observable has completed, return the validation status
- if an observable encounter error, all observable under the chain will not trigger
- when an error occur, triggers the error handler, and return the condition base on however much was modified
- once condition is finalized, map its structure for ValidationModal

**Caveat:**
my method relies heavily on the observable to COMPLETE and does not works with actual streams